# Using c++11's std::thread, when is modifying global variables thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++

Consider this source:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int *up;

void testf(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        for(int f = 0; f < 11; f++)
            up[i]++;
}

int main() {
    up = new int[1000];

    std::thread tt[7];

    for(int ts=0;ts<7;ts++) {
        tt[ts]=std::thread(testf);
    }

    for(int ts=0;ts<7;ts++) {
        tt[ts].join();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        cout << up[i];
    cout << endl;
    delete[] up;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm purposely writing to the same int array without any mutex. The for loop in `testf()` will increment all members of `int up[1000]` by 11, and we have 7 threads. So the output should be 77777777... (2000 Sevens)

But sometimes when I run the exe, I get a patch of numbers like this:

```
...7777777066676672756866667777777777777377777366667777777...
```

Why does this happen?

(to compile on linux: g++ -std=c++11 -pthread )

Comment: Your code has a data race and thus undefined behaviour.

Comment: And the question title is extremely misleading. You're never accessing a `std::thread` object concurrently, so the question isn't about the thread safety of `std::thread` at all.

Comment: Your `testf`  is really too quick. Replace 1000 by at least 1000000. And compile with optimizations, e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -O1 -g -Wall`

Comment: "I'm purposely writing to the same int array without any mutex." + "Why does this happen?"...???  What a question!  You obviously know there's something related called a "mutex" - why not go read what they're for?

Comment: As you (sort of) recognized, Im well aware of mutex's and there function. The question wasn't when to use a mutex, but why i++; isn't thread safe.

Comment: @JacobOJKolding The `i++` is thread safe, since it deals with a local variable that is only visible in the thread.  The `up[i]` isn't thread safe, because `up[i]` will be modified, and _is_ accessed by more than one thread.

Comment: I wasn't referring to i++ in regards to a for loop since it makes no since to discuss whether a local variable is thread safe and also there are two for loops in the code with an i variable. I was simply referring to the general case of incrementing a global variable in a thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that "up[i]++;" is not a thread safe operation. It does basically this:

1. read value of up[i]
2. add one to the read value
3. write value of up[i]

With two threads what should happen:

- Thread1 1) read value of up[i] (3)
- Thread1 2) add one to the read value (4)
- Thread1 3) write value of up[i] (4)
- Thread2 1) read value of up[i] (4)
- Thread2 2) add one to the read value (5)
- Thread2 3) write value of up[i] (5)

What could happen:

- Thread1 1) read value of up[i] (3)
- Thread2 1) read value of up[i] (3)
- Thread1 2) add one to the read value (4)
- Thread1 3) write value of up[i] (4)
- Thread2 2) add one to the read value (4)
- Thread2 3) write value of up[i] (4)

So both threads write 4 to the array!

To solve this, you either need a mutex or an atomic increment operation on the array:
http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/07/c11-concurrency-tutorial-part-4-atomic-type.html

Comment: That's a possible (and even probable) explication of what is actually happening in his immediate program, but the real answer is more general: if an object is accessed by more than one thread, and modified in any way, _all_ accesses to it (not just the writes) must be synchronized, or undefined behavior occurs.